Is there a topology of "convergence in average"?
A topology induces a notion of convergence, and the reverse implication is false in general - not every notion of convergence is induced by a topology, with the standard example being that of (global) convergence in measure.
Consider the following notion of convergence:
A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to 'converge in average (CIA)' to a quantity $A$ if the sequence
$$
S_n := \frac{a_1 + ... + a_n}{n}
$$
converges to $A$ in the usual sense.
Note also that convergence implies convergence in average, but not the converse.
I am wondering if there exists a topology on the reals in which the convergence of a sequence is precisely convergence in average.

That's a slightly confused notion of convergence of a "series," it is more closely related to convergence of the sequence $a_n.$ That is, if $a_n\to L,$ then $S_n\to L.$ There is a notion of a Cesaro sum, however.

In other words, if $\sum_{i\in \mathbb N} a_i$ converges in the traditional sense, $S_n\to0.$

You're correct. I have edited the question with the "actual" thing I had in mind, which I mis-presented originally. Thanks for the catch.

There is no such topology.  Convergence in a topology has the property that if a sequence converges to some limit $L$, then so does every subsequence.  But if we consider the sequence $0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots$ we see it converges "in average" to 0.5, which is not true of its all-zero subsequence.
